# GitHub Pages display custom domain in address bar

Tags: javascript, html, github, url, github-pages

How can I display a custom domain in the address bar of my GitHub Pages site. It is a shared domain name so CNAME records are restricted.

Is there any way I can edit my JS/HTML code such that it displays my domain name in the address bar?

I tried
`window.location.href = "www.mysite.site.com";`
But that results in the address being `username.github.io/www.mysite.site.com`.

Thank you.

Comment: Can I change the domain in the addressbar using HTML and JavaScript? No. You can't.

Comment: Using app code, Not as far as I know.
But you can setup a proxy if you have a registered domain name.
Such as cloudfare.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the `domain` of a website via javascript, if you could, that would be a **security vulnerability**.

Imagine having the power to make any website appear to be any other website.

`window.location.href` only changes the path after the domain

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://` or `https://` in the domain.
As: `window.location.href = "https://mysite.site.com";`

And this will redirect to `https://mysite.site.com` and not `username.github.io/www.mysite.site.com`.
And if you only want the browser to change the address and do not reload, then you can use:

```
<body onload="ChangeUrl('Title', '/page-adress.html');">
<script type="text/javascript">  
function ChangeUrl(title, url) {  
    if (typeof(history.pushState) != "undefined") {  
        var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };  
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);  
    } else {  
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");  
    }  
}  
</script>
```

**OR**

You can also use :

```
<body onload="function1">
    <script>
    function function1() {
      location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com")
    }
    </script>
```

It also redirects but disables the back button to navigate to the last page.